# Are there ways to randomly sample among ties in the R function which.max()?

Tags: r

I currently am using the `which.max()` function in `R` within a loop. Sometimes, I have a vector which contains the same elements, like:

```
vec <- c(0,0,2,0,2)
```

The function will then always return:

```
> which.max(vec)
[1] 3
```

I am wondering if there is a simple solution to break ties randomly so that it doesn't always choose the smallest index among ties. I know that there is a `which.is.max` function in `nnet`, but was hoping to see if there was another simple solution without having to resort to installing extra packages. Thanks.

Comment: See `?max.col` after converting "vec" to a 1-row matrix

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`which(vec == max(vec))` will match all ties. You can then pick one at random using `sample(which(vec == max(vec)), 1)`.

As you mentioned in the comments, `sample` does something annoying when the supplied vector is of length 1. So when there is only one maximum.

You can fix this as follows:

```
maxima <- which(vec == max(vec))
if(length(maxima) > 1){
  maxima <- sample(maxima, 1)
}
```

Comment: It seems that in the event when there is a clear maximum (i.e., only one value is the maximum, like `c(0,0,1,0`), this code then has sample(3,1), which will then sample from a pool of `1,2,3`. Is there a way to prevent it from sampling when there is one distinct maximum?

Comment: Note that this is almost exactly the same implementation as that used by `nnet::which.is.max`.

Comment: @Hugh that doesn't surprise me :P

Answer (score 12):

Another method is using `rank` with `ties.method = "random"` and then we can use `which.max` on it.

```
which.max(rank(vec, ties.method = "random"))

which.max(rank(vec, ties.method = "random"))
#[1] 3

which.max(rank(vec, ties.method = "random"))
#[1] 5
```

`rank` would basically rank the vector according to their value and with `ties.method = "random"` it will randomly assign rank in case of a tie.

```
rank(vec, ties.method = "random")
#[1] 2 1 4 3 5

rank(vec, ties.method = "random")
#[1] 1 3 5 2 4
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but a potential concern with this method is that rank requires sorting the vector, which doesn't scale as nicely for larger vectors.

Comment: @JAD hmm..maybe, I am not sure how `rank` works internally. Haven't checked for efficiency and I doubt if that should be a potential reason for a dv especially when OP hasn't mentioned anything about efficiency at first place. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I don't think so either, but just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called "pertubation", where you modify each number by a random amount that is significantly smaller than the existing variation. You can then take the maximum amount, which will be one of the original maxima plus some random amount. Which one of the original maxima will be selected is random, as it's determined by which had the largest random amount added. So for instance, if all your numbers are integers, you can convert them to floats, add a random number between 0 and .001, pick the largest one, and then round it back to int. This is probably not the most efficient method, but given that you mentioned the `which.is.max` in `nnet`, presumably you are doing work with neural networks, and pertubation is an important concept with NNs.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative:

```
vec <- c(0,0,2,0,2)
vec %>% unique %>% sapply(function(x) which(x==vec)[sample(x=length(which(x==vec)),1)])
```